# compare items on a list except to yourself

Tags: c#

I want to compare items in a list, but I don't want it to be compared to itself. How do I do that?
My code:

```
var students = new List<Student>() {
                new Student(){ Id = 1, Name="Bill"},
                new Student(){ Id = 2, Name="Steve"},
                new Student(){ Id = 3, Name="Ram"},
            };

for (int i=0; i<students.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < students.Count(); x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(students[i].Name + "   --   " + students[x].Name);
    }
}
```

this code returns...

```
Bill   --   Bill
Bill   --   Steve
Bill   --   Ram

Steve   --   Bill
Steve   --   Steve
Steve   --   Ram

Ram   --   Bill
Ram   --   Steve
Ram   --   Ram
```

Comment: The two `Student` objects you access are at index `i` and `x` in your list. What is the relationship between `i` and `x` when `students[i]` is the same as `students[x]`? What flow-control statement do you need to use to prevent writing to the console when this relationship exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```cs
var students = new List<Student>() {
                new Student(){ Id = 1, Name="Bill"},
                new Student(){ Id = 2, Name="Steve"},
                new Student(){ Id = 3, Name="Ram"},
            };

for (int i=0; i<students.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < students.Count(); x++)
    {
        if(students[i].Id != students[x].Id)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(students[i].Name + "   --   " + students[x].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

then you'll get:

```
Bill   --   Steve
Bill   --   Ram

Steve   --   Bill
Steve   --   Ram

Ram   --   Bill
Ram   --   Steve
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with C# Linq query in you first for

```
for (int i=0; i<students.Count; i++)
    {           
        IEnumerable<Student> compare = students.Where(s => s.Id != students[i].Id);
        
        foreach(var c in compare)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(students[i].Name + " -- " + c.Name);
        }
    }
```

The IEnumerable class would have all the elements except the one who are you comparing

The Result will be

```
Bill -- Steve
Bill -- Ram
Steve -- Bill
Steve -- Ram
Ram -- Bill
Ram -- Steve
```